# pass parameter to controller

Tags: controllers

Is it possible in magento to send parameter to controller form?

```
    $x=987654;
    $url=Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("/label/setlabel");
    $block->addButton('label', array(
                     "label" => "Get Label",
                     "onclick" =>"popWin('$url', 'windowname', 'width=400,height=300,scrollbars=yes')
                                    )
    );"
```

controller file:

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Adminhtml_LabelController
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function setlabelAction()
        {
           echo $x;//is this possible?
        }
}
```

I have this $x parmeter, is it possible somehow to send it to controller and echo it there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send that parameter through `GET` by making the url look like this:

```
$url=Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("/label/setlabel", array('param_name'=>$paramValue));
```

So in your case it can be

```
 $url=Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("/label/setlabel", array('x'=>$x));
```

Then you can read it in the controller like this:

```
$x = $this->getRequest()->getParam('x');
```

Comment: damn Marius, you're too fast